# Simplifying many if statements

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to simplify the if statements instead of typing `fifth_turn == each_turn_before`

```
table()

fifth_turn = int(input('Player #1, select the spot you desire: '))


if fifth_turn == first_turn or fifth_turn == second_turn or fifth_turn == third_turn or fifth_turn == fourth_turn:
    print('Spot Taken')
elif fifth_turn == 1:
    spot1 = 'x'
elif fifth_turn == 2:
    spot2 = 'x'
elif fifth_turn == 3:
    spot3 = 'x'
elif fifth_turn == 4:
    spot4 = 'x'
elif fifth_turn == 5:
    spot5 = 'x'
elif fifth_turn == 6:
    spot6 = 'x'
elif fifth_turn == 7:
    spot7 = 'x'
elif fifth_turn == 8:
    spot8 = 'x'
elif fifth_turn == 9:
    spot9 = 'x'
else:
    print('ERROR')
```

Comment: Please format the code properly.

Comment: And come up with a decent title please.

Comment: This can be simplified by keeping the turns in a list and running through the list with a for-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot that can be improved in your code by organizing spots into a list and using the `in` operator:

```
spots = [spot1, spot2, spot3, ... spot9] # Initialize the list

fifth_turn = int(input('Player #1, select the spot you desire: '))    

if fifth_turn in first_turn, second_turn, third_turn, fourth_turn:
    print('Spot Taken')
elif 1 <= fifth_turn <= 9:
    spots[fifth_turn - 1] = 'x'
else:
    print('ERROR')
```

Incidentally, printing "ERROR" is very uninformative because it does not tell the user what actually happened and how to fix it.

You should also consider having a list of turns instead of five (or more?) turn variables:

```
spots = [spot1, spot2, spot3, ... spot9] # Initialize the list
turns = [...] # Initialize the list

turns[4] = int(input('Player #1, select the spot you desire: '))    

if turns[4] in turns[:4]:
    print('Spot Taken')
elif 1 <= turns[4] <= 9:
    spots[turns[4] - 1] = 'x'
else:
    print('ERROR')
```

If you are trying to program tic-tac-toe, other optimizations are possible (like not having the list of turns at all).

Answer (score 0):

If I do not misunderstand what you're trying to do, I think it can be done more efficiently using a list.

```
spot = ['O' for i in range(9)]  # ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
turn = int(input('Player #1, select the spot you desire: '))

if spot[turn - 1] == 'X':  # Zero-indexed list
    print("Spot taken")
else:
    spot[turn - 1] = 'X'  # e.g. ['O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
```